# preposition: by one minute

Tags: prepositions

What does "by one minute" mean in the following?

> Rolls-Royce said in a press statement the Spirit of Innovation set three world records in total, including reaching 345.4 mph over 1.86 miles on 16 November. The company also said the vehicle achieved the fastest time to ascend 3000 meters **by one minute**, with a time of 202 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it is the fastest vehicle to ascend 3000 m and that the next fastest vehicle is ***one minute behind***.

It is this meaning of *by* that is used:

> 9: in or to the amount or extent of
>
> - win by a nose ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by))

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by) defines it in this way

> 17. PREPOSITION
>     If something increases or decreases ***by a particular amount***, that amount is gained or lost.
>
> - Violent crime has increased ***by** 10 percent* since last year.

Edit: Here is a more explicit usage:

> The Argentinian driver, partnered by Spain's Dani Oliveras in their BRX Prodrive Hunter, *was ***fastest by one minute and six seconds*** from Sweden's Mattias Ekstrom* on the 348- km sixth special as he continued his climb up the rankings to seventh overall. ([source](https://www.newsofbahrain.com/sports/77869.html))

Comment: Thank you. But the original sentence does not use a "comparison" verb like "increase" or "beat."

Comment: It is true, but it is implied: _by one minute (ahead of the next fastest vehicle)_.

Comment: CNN often offers awkward sentences, and I am not sure if it is one of them.

Comment: I don't see why you doubt the phrase. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fastest+by+*++minute%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&sxsrf=AOaemvL__Vl1dCdrZDOaWo4S8l8ybGdWAw%3A1642065327980&ei=r-3fYYOXO8SW8gL56bDoCw&ved=0ahUKEwjDqsmEsq71AhVEi1wKHfk0DL0Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22fastest+by+*++minute%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoECCMQJ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFDxDViJUWDpY2gBcAJ4AIAB1wGIAYYFkgEFNi4wLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) are plenty of examples.

Comment: I suspect it would have been better to say, "the vehicle achieved a **faster** time to ascend 3000 meters than the previous record by one minute."

Comment: You would loose the important meaning that that vehicle is THE FASTEST. This is just the idiomatic way to put it, that's all.

Comment: The meaning would not be lost; if the vehicle is faster than the previously fastest one, it is currently the fastest.

Comment: Maybe only a native speaker can determine if the usage in question is sloppy.

Comment: I have lived in the UK for the last 16 years and I have studied languages at the university. But yes, I am not a native speaker. I doubt however that any native would characterise this usage as "sloppy". Your reasoning is rather non-native. English doesn't work that way.

Comment: well, it's hard to say whether the reasoning is non-native. Even natives don't always agree among themselves.

Comment: Suit yourself. I will not harp on.

Comment: An Irish person says it doesn't make sense: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-fastest-time-to-ascend-3000-meters-by-one-minute.3898650/#post-19944312